# Menu Image size not Changing via css

Tags: html, css

I have this menu bar, which is replaced by Images.
All looks good on normal view, but when I swtich to mobile view 
It looks so clumsy. I tried Padding, But the individual cell do not 
make up space with each other.
Here is the screenshot
[image]

```css
li.topmenu1 {
  height: 20px;
}
```

```html
<nav id="category" class="drawer_block pc">
  <ul class="category-nav">
    <li class="topmenu1">
      <a href="http://azlily.bex.jp/eccube_1/html"><img src="http://azlily.bex.jp/eccube_1/html/template/default/img/menu/home.png"></a>
    </li>
    <li class="topmenu2">
      <a href="http://azlily.bex.jp/eccube_1/html/products/list"> <img src="/eccube_1/html/template/default/img/menu/products.png"></a>
    </li>
    <li class="topmenu3">
      <a href="http://azlily.bex.jp/eccube_1/html/user_data/concept"><img src="/eccube_1/html/template/default/img/menu/about.png"></a>
    </li>
    <li class="topmenu4">
      <a href="http://azlily.bex.jp/eccube_1/html/user_data/howto"><img src="/eccube_1/html/template/default/img/menu/howtouse.png"></a>
    </li>
    <li class="topmenu5">
      <a href="http://azlily.bex.jp/eccube_1/html/user_data/column"><img src="/eccube_1/html/template/default/img/menu/column.png"></a>
    </li>
    <li class="topmenu8">
      <a href="http://azlily.bex.jp/eccube_1/html/user_data/faq"><img src="/eccube_1/html/template/default/img/menu/FAQ.png"></a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Note - I also tried to include FULL URL of the image 
but somehow its not showing up on snippets :/

Comment: try
li.topmenu1 img{ 
 //style
}

Comment: you can try to add css properties on `<img>` tag.

Comment: With `media screen `or without? for mobile view.

Comment: In `@media` query for mobile view.

Comment: Means `@media` for each and every menu item? there are 8 image on menu. tried `max height 100% ` but no luck too.

Comment: Add `min-height` to `<img>`.

Comment: This question is lacking a proper description of how you _want_ it to look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check this https://jsfiddle.net/1dvy2854/4/

```
.category-nav li  {
    display: inline-block;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .category-nav li  {
    display: block;
}
.category-nav li img {
    max-width: 65px;
    display: inline-block;
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the elements inside `category-nav` have correct margins and paddings.

If you want to make sure that the individual pictures for the menu look okay, you might want to set styles for the images one by one.

So, in your case you can edit the heights for all of your topmenu1, topmenu2...

Also, you can the inspect tool on Chrome to find what is causing problems like this in your CSS code. You can change the code live and see what change is causing what.

Comment: Yes I have set every menu items in their own `class` Desktop view is okay . Just it changes its height to bit clumsy in mobile view.

Comment: Try to inspect it with Chrome or any browser like that. It has an option for viewing it as it was on a mobile screen. Look it up. I'm sure you can find the problem from there. It is hard to help from here without seeing all the css code that controls the view.